# Sorting large datasets by any column/attribute

Tags: mysql, database, apache-spark, hadoop, elasticsearch

I have a MySQL database with ~20M entries (and growing) distributed in some tables. My system has a feature where this information is shown in pages. So, at this point so far so good, I just need to query using SQL doing some JOINs and limit the result set by the page size.

The problem is that now I need to implement the sorting feature, so the user can sort the data by any column. Adding indexes in all columns doesn't seems to be a good option and leave it without indexes will lead to a full table scan. And even worst: SQL's ORDER BY could be even slower when sorting by a joined column.

So I start thinking in another possibilities like integrate MySQL with Hadoop or Spark but I've no experience with that.

What is the right path to follow ? Haddop, Spark, ElasticSearch, or use another strategy with MySQL, or something else ?

Thanks.

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` makes little sense. When you don't provide an `ORDER BY` clause, the engine is free to return the rows in any order, making pagination quite erratic.

Comment: But, why are you showing 20 million rows in pages? Maybe you should limit the result set using some filtering condition first. I don't think any user will read page #150000.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @TheImpaler. I tried to keep the question as simple as possible. In practice I do use filtering and ordering by a single column. So I don't retrieve 20M rows. The problem is that with this modification, the filter could fetch anything and the sorting could be by any column.

Comment: 20m is peanuts, even for mysql. If you have thousands of users then performance could ve an issue but you state little otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably a combination of using indexes and ranged partitioning. Partitioning will effectively create many smaller tables that work together as one table and can be queried as one table.

One key benefit from using partitioning is partition pruning. This means that when you use certain columns in your where clause the query planner knows which partitions it needs to look in and which are irrelevant for that query. Only searching the relevant partitions makes the query much faster. You can range partition a table on something like a date column or an auto-increment int (serial).

Other types of partitioning include hash and list. Hash and list are generally more useful if you are querying based on specific values. This is why I suggest ranged partitioning.

Here is a good general resource bout partitioning tables: [Everything You Need to Know About MySQL Partitions](https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/everything-you-need-to-know-about-mysql-partitions)

The chosen answer on this StackExchange question is about adding partitioning to a table that already exists: [How do I add a partition to an existing table in mariadb / mysql?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/219748/how-do-i-add-a-partition-to-an-existing-table-in-mariadb-mysql)

Comment: Yes, but partition usually work for a single column ordering. If the OP has multiple ones (it seems it's the case), then partitioning won't help for the other orderings.

Comment: As of MySQL 5.5, Columns partitioning was added. This means that multiple columns can be used for the key that determines ranged or list partitioning. The OP could use a multi column key for the partition and then partition pruning could be used for a where clause or sort containing any of those columns. Range and list partitioning also allow partitioning based on non-integer columns now as well. There will be some gaps still, yes. Without major schema normalization, this is probably the best solution. Column partitioning docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-columns.html

Comment: Yes, but as you say this still works for a single key (even if it's composed of multiple columns). However, the OP needs multiple separated criteria. +1 for the effort, since it may prove useful for **one** ordering criteria, maybe the most important one.

Comment: Thanks guys. @TheImpaler is correct, I need multiple/different criteria. So I'm not sure if MySQL partitioning is the correct answer for this.